# DataGrid LostFocus Event Raised when User Changes Row

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid

Here is the XAML used to create a datagrid:

```
<DataGrid
            x:Name="dgrComments"
            Height="200">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn
                Binding="{Binding Path=RepairID}"
                Visibility="Hidden" />
            <DataGridTextColumn
                Binding="{Binding Path=Sequence}"
                Visibility="Hidden" />
            <DataGridTextColumn
                Binding="{Binding Path=Entry}"
                DisplayIndex="0" />
            <DataGridTextColumn
                Binding="{Binding Path=LastUpdate}"
                Visibility="Hidden" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Here is how I bind data to the grid ("Sequence" is a column in the RepairComments table):

```
RepairFilter=<a text string that is a valid filter>
dvComments = New DataView(dsPIM.Tables("RepairDetails"), RepairFilter, "Sequence", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)
dgrComments.ItemsSource = dvComments
```

This all works fine EXCEPT that the datagrid dgrComments.LostFocus event is firing whenever the the user changes the selected row.  Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with DataGrid.LostFocus is that it is fired with every cell edit.

This is not always a bad thing, as it is useful to process a cell update or register a change of cell.

This is annoyng however, if you want to detect when a user leaves the DataGrid, as a whole, to another control elsewhere on the page.

The solution is to detect what exactly is now in focus, and determine if that is inside or outside the DataGrid.

To do this we can use the FocusManager to get the currently focussed element.
Then we simply check to see if the parent container is part of the DataGrid.

If it is not, we know it is outside the DataGrid and this signifies our DataGrid.LostFocus event.

```
private void dgrComments_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    Control ctrl = FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(this) as Control;  
    if (ctrl.Parent != null && ctrl.Parent.GetType() != typeof(DataGridCell)) 
        MessageBox.Show("outside!"); 
}
```

Adapted from [code.msdn.com](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/DataGrid-Lost-Focus-46bb4526) .

Comment: Actually, the LostFocus event is fired even if no editing is done at all.  Just changing the selected cell fires the event.  Too bad that is not mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: correct ! please mark my answer as correct if it address your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution if you have CollectionViewSource property

```
    private CollectionViewSource epairDetailsViewSource;

    private void FormItems_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        repairDetailsViewSource= ((CollectionViewSource)this.FindResource("repairDetailsViewSource"));

        context = new MyDbContext();
        context.RepairDetails.Load();

        repairDetailsViewSource.Source = context.Items.Local;

        repairDetailsViewSource.View.CurrentChanging += View_CurrentChanging;
    }

    private void View_CurrentChanging(object sender, CurrentChangingEventArgs e)
    {
        ((RepairDetails)repairDetailsViewSource.View.CurrentItem).//...
    }
```